# Making Audio Plugin for DAWs

Tags: audio, plugins, vst, ableton-live

I want to create a really simple Ableton plugin with a GUI. The only functionality I want is taking the keyboard signal and manipulate the midi output (For example, if I press A from keyboard *-where it normally plays note in Ableton*, I want to midi output C-maj - 3 notes).

I found a library called Juce but it's pretty expensive. The other libraries I found are for advanced stuff like making a synthesiser. What is the best/easiest way to achieve manipulating midi input? Or is low level code required for such task?

Comment: Why not just use any of the existing software that does this?

Comment: @Brad can you suggest me any?

Comment: I used to use GlovePIE.

Comment: I realize you want to make a plugin for many different DAWs, but if you're really only trying to build for one, many DAWs have scripting engines that can easily accomplish things like this (Reaper's ReaScript, Logic has something like it, Ardour's Lua, etc.).

Comment: I found Juce very interesting for cross-platform plugins. Everything except price seems brilliant.

Comment: Note that JUCE is only expensive if you're planning on selling your work as closed source. If you release your work under the GPL, you can use JUCE with no charge. If you're planning on selling what you use JUCE for, only then do you need the commercial license.

Answer (score 0):

If you know C# (or VB.NET) you can try using [VST.NET](http://vstnet.codeplex.com). It is a managed VST 2.4 framework excellent for the kind of plugin you want to build. It also comes with a few examples and one Midi-Mapper example that will probably something you can use to start of with.

Hope it helps,
Marc (author of VST.NET and MIDI.NET)

Comment: I am on a macbook osx. Does this only work for windows?